# Change datatype from Text to Text Area(Long)

Tags: data-types, long-text-area, text

I have a requirement where a text field char size(255) is not sufficient and I have used that text field in various codes.

If I **change datatype from Text to Text Area (Long)** will my other functionality get hampered ?

Comment: It shouldn't.. you can try this in any sandbox

Comment: you can refer this page for considerations while changing data type [Notes on Changing Data Type](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&language=en).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your text field is referenced anywhere in Apex code, you won't be able to change the data type until all references are removed.

See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/51727/13648) for more information on exactly what is involved in doing this.

Other than that (admittedly considerable) issue, there should not be any problems changing from a text field to a long text area. You should not experience any data loss as they are compatible fields.