# Changing field from Text Area to Text Area (Long) results in cannot change type due to data loss. Why?

Tags: change-set, long-text-area, text

On a sandbox I commented out references of a text area field from :
ApexClass, ApexPage, EmailTemplate, 2 Flows, and a layout.  I then was able to make the change of the data type just fine.

Now when I am trying to push my changes using a changeset on autorabit to the QA sandbox,  I am unable to deploy as it fails on the CustomField saying:

```
Cannot change type due to existing data.
```

I looked at a few examples like [Change datatype from Text to Text Area(Long)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103175/change-datatype-from-text-to-text-arealong) and [Change field Data Type without removing all references to said field in Controllers and Classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51705/change-field-data-type-without-removing-all-references-to-said-field-in-controll) where it says that there shouldn't be any data loss. So why am I seeing this error?

I also saw https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327186&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 and I don't have any references to that field in formulas etc. "Where is this used" shows no usage anywhere.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is the commented out references to this field being removed from the ApexClass, etc in the same package?

Comment: Yes they are being removed in the same package. @Kris Goncalves

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove my field from Process Builder formula and re-add it after change.